# the largest rectangle in a histogram

Tags: c, arrays, function, stack

i am trying to write a code to compute the area of he largest rectangle in a histogram and it's top coordinates.
for this purpose I am making the use of stacks in order to get the smaller bar to left and right in  case of each bar.

as per the guidlines from a GeeksForGeeks article, i am following these steps:

"1) Create an empty stack.

2) Start from first bar, and do following for every bar ‘hist[i]’ where ‘i’ varies from 0 to n-1.
……a) If stack is empty or hist[i] is higher than the bar at top of stack, then push ‘i’ to stack.
……b) If this bar is smaller than the top of stack, then keep removing the top of stack while top of the stack is greater. Let the removed bar be hist[tp]. Calculate area of rectangle with hist[tp] as smallest bar. For hist[tp], the ‘left index’ is previous (previous to tp) item in stack and ‘right index’ is ‘i’ (current index).

3) If the stack is not empty, then one by one remove all bars from stack and do step 2.b for every removed bar."

but my code is giving me some arbitrarily large values, suspected to be address values.
 please help me debug.

here is my code:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void maxRectangle(int hist[], int n);
void push(int stack[],int item,int *top,int n);
int pop(int stack[],int *top);
int peek(int stack[],int *top);
int isEmpty(int top);
int isFull(int top,int n);
void display(int stack[],int top);
int main()
{

    int n,i;
    printf("How many bars do you want to enter in the histogram?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int hist[n];
    printf("enter the hights of the consecutive bars\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&hist[i]);
    }

    maxRectangle(hist,n);
    return 0;
}

void maxRectangle(int hist[], int n)
{

    int top=-1;
    int i;
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    int max_area,idx, top_area;
    int stack[n];
    int bar=stack[top];

    while(i<n)
    {
    if(isEmpty(top)||(hist[bar]<hist[i]))
    {
        push(stack,i,&top,n);i++;
    }
    else
    {
        idx=peek(stack,&top); //smaller idx to the right
        pop(stack,&top); //bar idx  to compute the area for
        top_area= hist[idx]*(isEmpty(top)?i:i-peek(stack,&top)-1); //top(stack)is the smaller bar to the left
        if(top_area<max_area)
        {
            max_area=top_area;
            x1=(peek(stack,&top)+1);
            x2=idx+1;
            y1=y2=hist[idx];
        }
    }



    }

    printf("the largest area is %d, the top left coordinate is (%d,%d) and top-right coordinate is (%d,%d)\n",max_area,x1,y1,x2,y2);
}
void push(int stack[],int item,int *top,int n)
{
    if(isFull(*top,n))
    {
        printf("stack overflow!!\n");
        return;
    }
    *top=*top+1;
    stack[*top]=item;
}
int pop(int stack[],int *top)
{

    int item;
    if(isEmpty(*top))
    {
        printf("stack underflow!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    item=stack[*top];
    *top=*top-1;
    return item;

}
int peek(int stack[],int *top)
{
    if(isEmpty(*top))
    {
        printf("stack underflow!");
        exit(1);
    }
    return stack[*top];
}
int isEmpty(int top)
{
    if(top==-1) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
int isFull(int top,int n)
{
    if(top==(n-1)) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void display(int stack[],int top)
{
    int i;
    printf("stack elements are:\n\n");
    for(i=top;i>=0;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",stack[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

`

Comment: `stack[-1]` isn't going to end well. You do this at `int bar=stack[top]` where `top == -1`

Comment: what did you see when you walked through with your debugger?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here.

1. `int bar = stack[top];` is bad because `top = -1`
2. Most of your variables are uninitialized.  This is the reason they are odd values.
3. `isEmpty(top)||hist[bar]<hist[i]` will always return true, so you only ever push.
4. `if(top_area<max_area)` is backwards if you want the largest area

There are other, smaller issues but if you fix these, your program will function properly.